# How do I limit the size of my syslog?

Tags: syslog, usbfs

I've got my mom's computer running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. It's been working just fine but all of the sudden syslog has been filling up. And by filling up I mean I just deleted a `/var/log/syslog` that was 400GB in size. Yes - Gigabytes.

While I'm sure there was some useful information in there, I'm not sure that 400GB is any kind of information to sift through. And what's really amazing about it is that it happened within a period of 8 hours - I had ran `df` around noon, and between then and now her drive filled up 30% (from just under 70% to 100%).

What could be causing this and how could I fix it?`

**EDIT**
Looks like the usb is the offender:

```
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157829] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157836] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157842] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157849] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157857] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157863] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157870] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157877] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157884] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
Sep  8 08:52:10 pamela-desktop kernel: [ 6198.157891] usb 1-3: usbfs: process 1500 (demond_nscan) did not claim interface 3 before use
```

Comment: I'd say that instead of limiting the size, you should be trying to figure out what fills it. There should be lots of repeated messages, try running `tail -n20 /var/log/syslog` to have a look at the last 20 lines.

Comment: I did try that before hosing the file - nothing seemed to be repeated, but I'll take a look again

Comment: So this looks like the problem is "demond_nscan", which I don't find anything about on google.  `nscan` is a port-scanning application, so this might be someone's modification of it (but I'm just theorizing).  If this isn't an application you are explicitly trying to run, I recommend trying to find the executable (something like `find / -iname demond_nscan`), and renaming it/changing it's permissions so it's not executable.  (This way, if it's actually important for something, you haven't lost it, and if it's been launched by something else, you might notice.  Also, check `crontab -l`?

Comment: demond_nscan looks like it's related to the lexmark scan drivers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should find out what is causing the large amount of messages, as if you fix this issue then you fix the large log file.

However, until then you can put in a log rotation base on one of the below.

- **time** ( eg. rotate every day )
- **size** ( eg. rotate when the file reaches 10mb )

This will already be setup on the system by default: **/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog**

```
 /var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
            reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
    endscript
 }
```

From this you can see that it will rotate he /var/log/syslog file **daily** and keep **7 copies** of the rotated file.

You can change this to be rotate on a size limit, say 1mb or reduce how many copies it stores.

**Warning: This will not fix the root cause of your issue**, however it will buy you some time as it will stop the file system from filling up.

- Source: /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
- Source: man logrotate

Comment: This will not limit the size of the actual syslog!

Answer (score 30):

### Limit the size of logrotate

Open the `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` config file

```
sudo nano /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

The file looks sth. like

```
/var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
    endscript
}
....
...
```

Add e.g. `size 100k`  in the parenthesis. Afterwards it should look like:

```
/var/log/syslog
{
    rotate 7
    size 100k
    daily
    missingok
    notifempty
    delaycompress
    compress
    postrotate
        /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
    endscript
}
```

Note, that this limits the file size of the rotating files, and not the actual syslog file.
Save the file. The next time the logrotate chron job starts, it will limit the size of the rotated logs.

### Limit the size of the current syslog

To limit the size of `/var/log/syslog`, you have to edit the `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, and set a fixed log size.

Add or modify this setting, by changing the following line in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`:

```
.*;auth,authpriv.none       -/var/log/syslog
```

Here an excerpt of [rsyslog manual](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/output_channels.html?highlight=outchannel) :

> **Output channels** are defined via an $outchannel directive. It’s syntax
> is as follows:
>
> `$outchannel name,file-name,max-size,action-on-max-size`
>
> name is the name of the output channel (not the file), file-name is
> the file name to be written to, max-size the maximum allowed size and
> action-on-max-size a command to be issued when the max size is
> reached. This command always has exactly one parameter. The binary is
> that part of action-on-max-size before the first space, its parameter
> is everything behind that space. Please note that max-size is queried
> BEFORE writing the log message to the file. So be sure to set this
> limit reasonably low so that any message might fit. For the current
> release, setting it 1k lower than you expected is helpful. The
> max-size must always be specified in bytes - there are no special
> symbols (like 1k, 1m,…) at this point of development. Keep in mind
> that $outchannel just defines a channel with “name”. It does not
> activate it. To do so, you must use a selector line (see below). That
> selector line includes the channel name plus an $ sign in front of it.
> A sample might be: *.* :omfile:$mychannel In its current form, output
> channels primarily provide the ability to size-limit an output file.
> To do so, specify a maximum size. When this size is reached, rsyslogd
> will execute the action-on-max-size command and then reopen the file
> and retry. The command should be something like a log rotation script
> or a similar thing.
>
> If there is no action-on-max-size command or the command did not
> resolve the situation, the file is closed and never reopened by
> rsyslogd (except, of course, by huping it). This logic was integrated
> when we first experienced severe issues with files larger 2gb, which
> could lead to rsyslogd dumping core. In such cases, it is more
> appropriate to stop writing to a single file. Meanwhile, rsyslogd has
> been fixed to support files larger 2gb, but obviously only on file
> systems and operating system versions that do so. So it can still make
> sense to enforce a 2gb file size limit.

Here the max-size is 1MB, place this line before the `*.*;  ...` line

```
$outchannel mysyslog,/var/log/syslog,1048576
```

and change the `*.*;  ...` line into

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none  :omfile:$mysyslog
```

Restart rsyslogd ether with

```
sudo systemctl restart  rsyslog.service
```

or

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

To look at the rsyslog status type

```
systemctl status rsyslog.service
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Lexmark Pro915 for two weeks. I did two things, and it now works fine. I reinstalled the driver. (Don't think this was what helped.) I took out the USB extension I was using which made the total length almost 15' long and which might not have been entirely compatible. I suspect that the Lexmark driver for Linux systems might be detecting a poor, or poorly timed, signal and wanting to tell you about it 10 billion times a day. Try improving your connection somehow.

Logrotate and similar solutions didn't help me. Kern.log and syslog together were logging more than 1TB a day! Logrotate might help if you could set it to run every twelve minutes.

Comment: Agree. Logrotate with 1TB/ day ( or few hours in my case) is imho a way to burn your SSD.... In my case I know what is happening but can do nothing about it... Every time the pc is locked, if vlc is on, it starts complaining...