# Syslog/kernlog filling up with "did not claim interface N before use"

Tags: drivers, syslog, lexmark

As I discovered when asking [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/184949/658), it appears that `demond_nscan` is trying to use a device without claiming it. And it does it.... hundreds of time per second apparently. This makes `kern.log` and `syslog` *huge* (100GB >).

In this particular case the problem is directly a result of some Lexmark drivers that were installed (found at `/usr/local/lexmark/unix_scan_drivers/bin/demond_nscan`).

Here are a few things I know:

- The drivers are for an all-in-one printer/scanner device.
- There was a previous lexmark printer-only that was installed with CUPS
- This driver was the one for CUPS systems, and I think that it automatically added it to the list of printers in CUPS.
- The issue started spamming kern/syslog only after these drivers were installed, using the lexmark installers

While googling around I found [this thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/nut-upsuser@lists.alioth.debian.org/msg05598.html) that's not completely related, but it does mention that it might be happening when two drivers try to control the same device at the same time.

How can I resolve this issue so that either I only have one driver, or get the driver to claim the device before usage?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across this problem too.

What worked for me was completely purging the Lexmark scanner driver and re-installing it.

(The name of the package to purge is *lexmark-network-scan*)