# Systemd logs (`journalctl`) are too large and slow

Tags: command-line, performance, disk-usage, systemd, systemd-journald

My `journalctl` is keeping over 300 MB of logs as revealed by `journalctl --disk-usage`. Everything appears to be in order when I run `journalctl --verify`:

```
$ journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 328.0M on disk.

$ journalctl --verify
PASS: /var/log/journal/d7b25a27fe064cadb75a2f2f6ca7764e/system.journal    
PASS: /var/log/journal/d7b25a27fe064cadb75a2f2f6ca7764e/user-65534.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/d7b25a27fe064cadb75a2f2f6ca7764e/system@02f1aae76e32467390ab88ba03ae559e-0000000000000001-00056515dbdcd67e.journal
PASS: /var/log/journal/d7b25a27fe064cadb75a2f2f6ca7764e/user-1000.journal 
PASS: /var/log/journal/d7b25a27fe064cadb75a2f2f6ca7764e/user-65534@9838f64d6ee047bebec9d30d329064d4-00000000000005bb-00056515dbfe8d9d.journal
```

I noticed how slow the system is when I pipe to `grep` from `journalctl`.

How can I sensibly reduce the size of what I'm keeping in `journalctl`?

[image: Original .GIF image]

Comment: 300M is nothing... today again I had a VM with 2.2G of logs. The defaults are just crazy.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

### `systemd` comes with a nifty vacuum cleaner

To limit log files to a specific size `systemd` provides a `vacuum` feature to "suck out" older information from log files. The parameters allowed are:

```
 --vacuum-size=BYTES   Reduce disk usage below specified size
 --vacuum-files=INT    Leave only the specified number of journal files
 --vacuum-time=TIME    Remove journal files older than specified time
```

For example to reduce 312 MB consumption down to 200 MB (or less) use:

```
$ sudo journalctl --vacuum-size=200M
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/d7b25a27fe064cadb75a2f2f6ca7764e/system@00056515dbdd9a4e-a6fe2ec77e516045.journal~ (56.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/d7b25a27fe064cadb75a2f2f6ca7764e/user-65534@00056515dbfe731d-b7bab56cb4efcbf6.journal~ (8.0M).
Deleted archived journal /var/log/journal/d7b25a27fe064cadb75a2f2f6ca7764e/user-1000@1bbb77599cf14c65a18af51646751696-000000000000064f-00056444d58433e1.journal (112.0M).
Vacuuming done, freed 176.0M of archived journals on disk.
```

### Disk Space saved

The `journalctl` size is reduced substantially:

```
$ journalctl --disk-usage
Archived and active journals take up 136.0M on disk.
```

Size has dropped from 312 MB to 136 MB a savings of 176 MB and 64 MB more than expected. This is probably a one time anomaly due to an extraordinary large single log file. I'll revise this answer after a month if new info arises.

### Boot Logs reduced

The number of `journalctl` boot logs was 32 but now it is reduced to 26:

```
$ journalctl --list-boots
-26 0f230cc546fd4aec8f5233e0074ab3e1 Tue 2018-02-13 03:57:20 MST—Wed 2018-02-14 
-25 c0d2c0141dd840cbab75d3c2254f8781 Wed 2018-02-14 22:59:13 MST—Sat 2018-02-17 
-24 aafb2573a6374e019a7165cb8eee74a0 Sun 2018-02-18 06:02:03 MST—Mon 2018-02-19 
-23 8462f1969c6f4d61973e7e245014b846 Mon 2018-02-19 04:16:53 MST—Sat 2018-02-24 
-22 7f71ac2fb9714c49aa05989b741655f2 Sat 2018-02-24 04:24:36 MST—Sat 2018-02-24 
-21 b12a48c363474e5fb39311a166a98d54 Sat 2018-02-24 04:28:09 MST—Sun 2018-02-25 
-20 fbef1e659de64a0cbdcb9994f5a39457 Sun 2018-02-25 17:48:20 MST—Mon 2018-02-26 
-19 3d9b4c10f98d4ef7aab1cb2baa9b74e1 Mon 2018-02-26 08:37:01 MST—Mon 2018-02-26 
-18 4412b117dcc648aa9eceabcd0f205207 Mon 2018-02-26 08:38:00 MST—Mon 2018-02-26 
-17 f6794cbb7fb24213a6f2c3e368f666a1 Mon 2018-02-26 08:39:12 MST—Mon 2018-02-26 
-16 472f968506ed446ab12cf7abc65fa81a Mon 2018-02-26 08:49:37 MST—Mon 2018-02-26 
-15 d575c609d82e4ecd8dcebb70d40160d7 Mon 2018-02-26 17:07:36 MST—Mon 2018-02-26 
-14 878cfd9239a84dae80c62e7413c72951 Mon 2018-02-26 17:24:54 MST—Mon 2018-02-26 
-13 7f9913c7dbff46ab9bbd7c2cbefc4d7d Mon 2018-02-26 17:35:19 MST—Mon 2018-02-26 
-12 bf90829ef13a4e9fa1794bf0a88f4033 Mon 2018-02-26 17:45:12 MST—Wed 2018-02-28 
-11 fb879a836c7c459ab27f6332bee6013b Wed 2018-02-28 03:56:29 MST—Wed 2018-02-28 
-10 b0fec230765046f5bf3d654db1dc13ee Wed 2018-02-28 20:03:15 MST—Thu 2018-03-01 
 -9 72a2d6789eab4396be16348d9ead0408 Thu 2018-03-01 03:58:25 MST—Fri 2018-03-02 
 -8 8bccdc9b16124d26af05c34c8a30a0f5 Fri 2018-03-02 16:54:36 MST—Sat 2018-03-03 
 -7 40c2875db30349f5a9b1dfc849a47c05 Sat 2018-03-03 10:03:48 MST—Sat 2018-03-03 
 -6 781c79d2ec7946afba0fa2300e8ebe56 Sat 2018-03-03 10:04:34 MST—Sat 2018-03-03 
 -5 bb66dc875e414021940b7233072516d2 Sat 2018-03-03 17:43:08 MST—Tue 2018-03-06 
 -4 ba3bcfdc71584757b8bef9df16e7b0f6 Tue 2018-03-06 16:56:36 MST—Tue 2018-03-06 
 -3 60faa0fda99a4ef4b14b73c412d69e50 Tue 2018-03-06 17:00:47 MST—Tue 2018-03-06 
 -2 9b317bb8403344ca84dd2f288bc90410 Tue 2018-03-06 17:02:15 MST—Tue 2018-03-06 
 -1 dcb126be665a4531aae4312af7e51a34 Tue 2018-03-06 17:09:00 MST—Tue 2018-03-06 
  0 6a105af650d5442a9b03004165e58adf Tue 2018-03-06 17:42:45 MST—Wed 2018-03-07
```

### Performance improved

The time to verify `journalctl` integrity is noticeably quicker:

[image: journalctl verify 2.png]

Time has reduced from 10 seconds down to 4 seconds.

Credit to this [Source](https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/managing-journal-size/).

## Long Term Solutions

I've created a `cron` job to run the vacuum cleaner once a month.

Another option as mentioned in comments is to set `SystemMaxUse=50M` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`. There are actually four different places you can set the option:

```
/etc/systemd/journald.conf
/etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf
/run/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf
```

There are actually [many options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html) you can use for similar goals:

```
SystemMaxUse=, SystemKeepFree=, SystemMaxFileSize=, SystemMaxFiles=, RuntimeMaxUse=, RuntimeKeepFree=, RuntimeMaxFileSize=, RuntimeMaxFiles=
```

reload conf:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

Comment: This is a temporary fix, not a permanent solution. You should mention /etc/systemd/journald.conf `SystemMaxUse=50M`

Comment: @phiresky Thanks for pointing this out. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Of course now you don't have logs going back as far when you want to investigate a problem.  There's no reason for properly indexed log files to be slower as they get larger, its just a bad file format.

Comment: if you set `SystemMaxUse=50M` in  `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` , you have to restart `systemctl restart systemd-journald`

Answer (score 11):

You can instruct journalctl to display a smaller quantity of stuff. There are various ways of doing this, such as:

- `-u [unit]` or `--unit=[unit]`: this tells journalctl to only display logs from a systemd unit. You could, for example, type `journalctl -u NetworkManager.service`, and you'll get logs from NetworkManager.
- `-S [time]` or `--since=[time]`: This tells journalctl to ignore any entries from before a certain time, specified as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. If you want to leave out the time, journalctl will use 00:00:00, similarly :00 if you leave out seconds. Also, if you leave out the date, journalctl will use the current date. Here's an example, taken from the man page: `journalctl -S 2012-10-30 18:17:16`.
- `-U [time]` or `--until=[time]`: this is quite similar to the above, except it omits entries from **after** than the specified time. Arguments and syntax are the same.
- `-n [x]` or `--lines [x]`: limits the number of output lines, where "x" is an integer. If you type `journalctl -n 12`, only the twelve **most recent** logs will be displayed.

You can also reduce the amount of data retained, but WinEunuuchs2Unix already pointed that out, so I won't waste time repeating that information.

Comment: Looks like `journalctl` has a wealth of options and someone should write a `zenity` or `yad` front end with GUI drop down menus and radio buttons / check boxes to filter with. I am kind of tempted myself. +1 even though answer strays off spirit of question :)

Comment: Thank you, journalctl really contains built-in all the tools you need to manage the huge load of entries. Just adding that it should be `-S` not `-s` (i.e. a capital instead of lowercase), for the abbreviative option of `--since`