# How to detect why my ubuntu 18.04 is crashing multiple times

Tags: 16.04, firefox, java, 18.04, crash

I have been work around a new desktop (with 3 months of use) which has been freezng and crashing multiple times.

In the first 2 months I used the Ubuntu 16.04, and multiple times I have crash with the firefox browser and in java using Pycharm IDE.

One week ago I change to Ubuntu 18.04 (by a erase, repartitioning and reinstall). It have been show the same problem of frozen when I'm use the firefox or brave browser.

I don't know what I can do to find the problem. Maybe is my pci wifi adapter or not (sincerely I don't know what is happing).

In attached is the last crash (occurred at 21hs in Brazil time in 25/06/2018).

Any help I will save my life (I work at computer to finish my phd thesis, in a hurry...).

[image: image part 1]
[image: Image part 2]
[image: image part 3]

```
###################################
Running tests over the disks
```

Running a SMART test: Apparently there is no problem at the filesystem disk. 
[image: SMART test results]

```
Running the SMART test in the data disk 1.
```

[image: disk 1]

```
Running the SMART test for the disk 2.
```

[image: disk 2]

```
Runnning the SMART test in the backup disk.
```

[image: backup disk]

Comment: Have a look at '/var/log/syslog' to see if there is a hint there.

Comment: How can I find the error in the archive of "var/log/syslog"? Because there I found 127 "error" references at the log file...

Comment: the information from the pages you attached can be found in /var/crash/  (*even if you don't understand them, the file names themselves can contain clues as to which app crashed*); as John stated syslog; but I often find more info via `dmesg` & `journalctl`.  `dmesg` uses system time (secs.millisecs since boot) where as `journalctl` uses human.time :)

Comment: The first two fields of every line in '/var/log/syslog' are the date and time. If you know when the last crash occurred, look for entries that have a date and time just before the crash.

Comment: The next time your system crashes, reboot, go to the terminal and type `journalctl -b-1` to bring up the last boot. Then press the `End` key and it should show you what was happening just before the crash. Note this only works out of the box with 18.04. For 16.04 you have to turn on multiple boot logs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039101/how-do-you-manage-journald-log-history-on-ubuntu-core-16/1039213#1039213

Comment: systemd-udevd[2289]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sdf, 10) failed: No such file or directory
kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Asking for cache data failed
 kernel: sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
systemd-udevd[2289]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sdf, 10) failed: No such file or directory
systemd-udevd[3137]: inotify_add_watch(9, /dev/sdf1, 10) failed: No such file or directory

Comment: It would be more helpful to highlight the lines in your terminal and press `Ctrl`+`C` to copy them to your clipboard. Then edit your question and press `Ctrl`+`V` to paste the lines into your question. Finally highlight the lines within your question and press `{}` button on the page to insert four spaces in front of them to convert the paste into a code block. Then everyone can read it as intended.

Comment: Using the "journalctl -b-1" I found some red lines :

'kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e'
kernel: MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list

myserver kernel: Loaded UEFI:MokListRT cert 'Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority: '...' linked to secondary sys keyring

kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e

kernel: usb 1-9: device descriptor read/64, error -110
 
wpa_supplicant[1084]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none

wpa_supplicant[1084]: dbus: Failed to construct signal

Comment: Looks like hardware failure: Look up how to run memtest on your RAM and how to run SMART test on your storage.

Comment: I have been running a memtest (1 complete pass) and didn't find problem.

I'm running a smart test in the system disk (one SSD) after that I will run in the other disks.

Comment: I run the SMART test to the filesystem hardware and nothing wrong (I think)
Look at image above

Comment: Crashing again and showing the same message in red at "journalctl":              

**1)** kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e                                                 

**2)**    kernel: MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list        
               
**3)**   kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e                                     

**4)**   wpa_supplicant[1038]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none                                                      

**5)**    wpa_supplicant[1038]: dbus: Failed to construct signal

Comment: AFAIK `journalctl` only remembers the current boot by default cc @WinEunuuchs2Unix so you have to configure persistence to learn anything about a previous boot.

Comment: Zanna sorry no @ available with phone app. Yes if installed before Jan 2018 you have to turn on multiple boot logs. I have Q&A on that I'll link tonight.

Comment: I'm testing the hardware in last 2 days. Apparently after I drop out my wifi pci express card, the desktop stop to crash. But, today I'll work more intensivelly on that. And, after that I can answer better about.

Comment: @Zanna here is how you turn on multiple boot logs for 16.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/1008210/307523

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue. Could you please check if your [main memory works as intended](/q/591488/175814)? Thanks.

Comment: Also, could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: I have been testing my computer without pci express wifi card (using  usb wifi adapter) and all problems finish. 
In fact I dindn't get a correct answer by testing memory or other components, the answer was found by try and error.
I confirm the problem today, when I put the pci express card again, and imediatlty the cpu start tu frozen and crash. Thank you al!