# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Slow Boot

Tags: boot

I Everyone,
My laptop kind of slow in booting i just freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

`$ systemd-analyze`

```
Startup finished in 5.299s (firmware) + 4.531s (loader) + 4.298s (kernel) + 1min 1.884s (userspace) = 1min 16.014s graphical.target reached after 1min 1.833s in userspace
```

`$ systemd-analyze blame`

```
32.070s plymouth-quit-wait.service
17.799s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
15.529s snapd.service                                        
13.727s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
11.953s dev-sda2.device                                      
10.132s udisks2.service
```

`$ systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.
graphical.target @1min 1.833s
└─multi-user.target @1min 1.833s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @39.598s +295ms
     └─snapd.service @24.066s +15.529s
       └─basic.target @22.886s
          └─sockets.target @22.886s
            └─snapd.socket @22.885s +846us
               └─sysinit.target @22.799s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @22.362s +436ms
                        └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @21.968s +351ms
                            └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.167s +17.799s
                                 └─systemd-journald.service @3.640s +523ms
                                      └─systemd-journald.socket @3.633s
                                          └─system.slice @3.630s
                                               └─-.slice @3.630s
```

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1):

The `plymouth` service usually isn't to blame because it is simply waiting for other services to finish first. The biggest time drain is from: `systemd-journal-flush.service` which is described here:

- [What is the use of systemd-journal-flush.service?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094389/what-is-the-use-of-systemd-journal-flush-service)

After removing journal flushing at boot time, another helpful thread is here:

- [Systemd logs (`journalctl`) are too large and slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012912/systemd-logs-journalctl-are-too-large-and-slow)

Comment: thanks for the reply i will look into it