# How to set size for system log

Tags: log, rsyslog, logrotate

My server dumps because of huge system log files. I've heard that we could limit the size of system log by adding such a line `size 100m` into the file `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` to do so.

Now my `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` becomes as below:

```
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        size 100m
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

My question is: how does `size 100m` work with `rotate 7`?

Without `size 100m`, `rotate 7` and `daily` together mean that the system log will be rotated daily and it will keep 7 days worth of backlogs. Now if I add `size 100m` and some daily log is bigger than `100m`, will it rotate immediately? If so, does it mean that I may get 7 backlogs in a day if some daily log grows too much (more than `700mb`)?

Comment: Your question might be useful as it is, but practically, you should really find the underlying problem as logs shouldn't become huge. See [Very large log files, what should I do?](//askubuntu.com/q/515146) for example

Comment: The background of the question is useful; there must be some limit to any logfile, even if it's just physical disk or memory space. Better to manage that than to wait...  Regarding a solution: Apart from setting the logrotate limits, there is an answer by setting `max-size` on `Output channels`of `rsyslogd` pointed out in section "Limit the size of the current syslog" of [https://askubuntu.com/questions/184949/how-do-i-limit-the-size-of-my-syslog/1083570#1083570]. Disclaimer: did not validate that myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you realize that your using the `logrotate` mechanism does NOT control the size of the syslog file, it only will each day whenever logrotate is run, take the current `/var/log/syslog` file and if it is over 100MBytes, compress and save the result.  A new `/var/log/syslog` file is then created which starts receiving messages from that point forward.