# What are the options to manage the size of /var/log/syslog of an embedded system

Tags: systemd, log, syslog, logrotate, embedded-system

I have an embedded system (i.MX6) running a modified version of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS bionic stored on its SD card and I want to know how to manage /var/log/syslog file size.

I noticed that systemd journal doesn't manage that file when I type this :

```
journalctl --vacuum-size=10M
```

I really don't need systemd journals, but this is another issue...

Can someone confirm that systemd, apart from redirecting the standard output of services to /var/log/syslog (can be disabled apparently) does not propose anything else to manage syslog ?

Should I install "Logrotate" ? Since I'm using an SD card I should be careful and not to wear it out with an unsuitable configuration.

Are there other options ?

Comment: This can help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/184949/how-do-i-limit-the-size-of-my-syslog

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Systemd logs (\`journalctl\`) are too large and slow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012912/systemd-logs-journalctl-are-too-large-and-slow)

Comment: @PabloBianchi No but I posted a new question here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403205/how-to-disable-logging-to-var-log-syslog-and-use-only-systemd-logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I disabled Rsyslog and made systemd the only log manager of my embedded system since I can fix a limit of the log size in /etc/systemd/journald.conf

I prefer the UNIX philosophy and simple stuff (KISS) but systemd is already installed in the Ubuntu of the embedded system I'm working on so I will not complicate things for me.