# How to disable logging to /var/log/syslog and use only systemd logs

Tags: systemd, log, syslog, rsyslog, systemd-journald

My last question [What are the options to manage the size of /var/log/syslog of an embedded system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402615/what-are-the-options-to-manage-the-size-of-var-log-syslog-of-an-embedded-system) was not answered so I am asking this question to see if it is possible to stop using /var/log/syslog and just use the systemd logs.

I don't want this file to grow in the future (embedded system) and I don't want to use logrotate to manage it since I can use the systemd logs which are governed by the rules I can set in /etc/systemd/journald.conf.

In other words, I don't want to have two systems for logs. Personally, I prefer /etc/log/syslog because it's a text file while systemd's logs are binary, but since systemd manages its own log and is a component of the operating system that cannot be removed, I figure it's better to let it manage the system logs.

Is it enough to disable the transfer of log messages to syslog by setting the "ForwardToSyslog" key to "no" in "/etc/systemd/journald.conf" and stopping and disabling the rsyslog service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way would be to stop and disable the `rsyslog.service` and its corresponding `syslog.socket`:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable --now syslog.socket rsyslog.service
```

This should effectively disable `rsyslogd` from running.

On the same note, it should also be possible to disable the `systemd-journald.service` in the exact same way:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable --now systemd-journald.service
```

Comment: if I disable the redirection of log messages to syslog in the systemd configuration and disable Rsyslog, the /var/log/syslog file will no longer be used and I can delete it ?

Comment: Correct. Should you ever need `rsyslog` again, enabling and starting it should recreate the correct logfiles.